# HTML onclick image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, redirect

I'm working on this website and I need it to change the page through javascript, for now.
And whenever I click the image(acts as a search button), it doesn't do what it's supposed to.

So this is my form (note that I am using Foundation):

```
<form>
  <div class="ten columns" style="margin-left:0px">
      <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
  </div>
  <div class="two columns" style="margin-left:0px">
  <input type="image" src="img/search.png" width="20" height="20" onClick="return getSearch()"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's the `getSearch` function:

```
<script src="foundation/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="foundation/javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="foundation/javascripts/app.js"></script>

  <script>
function getSearch(){
    var searchValue = $('#search').val();
    if(searchValue == 'shirt'){
        window.location.href = "feed.html";
    }
}
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks, Joao.

Comment: And did you coincedently place that function inside a document ready funtion or something similar ?

Comment: _Where_ are you placing the function?

Comment: input type image? 90s called...

Comment: no, I didn't. I think it's not necessary since I only need it when I click the image(button)

Comment: @adeneo its being called in the persons onclick so no need for a .ready()

Comment: @jPratas do you have a demo where we can see your issue.

Comment: "_it doesn't do what it's supposed to_", What does it do?

Comment: @undefined it does absolutely nothing :(

Comment: Is that right above the body tag? In the head?... With JS you kind of need to be thorough with questions

Comment: change it to this: `window.getSearch = function (){`

Comment: @Shrink i'ts right below. Does it have to always above?

Comment: @CrayonViolent what part should I change into that?

Comment: change `function getSearch(){` to `window.getSearch = function (){`

Comment: Below it? Below the `</body>` or just above `</body>`?

Comment: below </body>, @Shrink

Comment: IOW I suspect the same as @adeneo that you have a scope issue. So this change explicitly defines it in the global scope. If that doesn't work then perhaps your form or this code is within an iframe?

Comment: You should stick it right above the `</body>`. And sometimes in the head of your document

Comment: @jPratas its submitting for me when I type in shirt but does nothing if it isn't shirt; http://codepen.io/aliuk12/pen/GwjLx/

Comment: @AlistairLaing thank you for your input. It happens that I just needed to change to <img src="".... instead of <input type="image"

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis thanks for the heads up as well... It's not that I'm new on HTML, I'm just new on HTML5 and I didn't know that it had been "deprecated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution :

**html:**

```
<form>
  <div class="ten columns" style="margin-left:0px">
      <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..."/>
  </div>
  <div class="two columns" style="margin-left:0px">
  <img src="img/search.png" width="20" height="20" id="myImg"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**js:**

```
  $("#myImg").click(function(){
    var searchValue = $('#search').val();
    if(searchValue == 'shirt'){
        window.location.href = "feed.html";
    }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/LgY2y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding return false to the function

```
function getSearch(){
    var searchValue = $('#search').val();
    if(searchValue == 'shirt'){
        window.location.href = "feed.html";
        return false;
    }
}
```